# SQLServer Compact y C# conexión

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Buena noche estoy aprendiendo a usar SQLServer Compact y al investigar encontre que se utiliza la libreria SqlServerCe y la implemente de esta forma pero no me sirve quería saber en donde esta mi error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace CoreBE
{
class SQLServerCompactControl
{
    public Boolean ShowErrors = true;
    public Boolean Error;
    public String MessageError;
    public String MessageStackTrace;
    private SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
 }
 }
```

me dan error estas dos líneas

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
    private SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
```

en uno me dice que la librería no se esta utilizando y en el otro me dice que el nombre no se encontró

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo logre resolver se tiene que agregar en referencias el dll de SQLServer Compact que viene en archivos de programa/Microsofot SQL Server Compact/V4.0/Private <- ahí dentro vienen los dll que se necesitan agregar